# Relacionar campos en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy creando una Base de Datos en MYSQL para usarla en un programa Java, os pongo como de momento he creado las dos primeras tablas:

```
create table cliente(
id_cliente int,
Nombre varchar(255),
Apellido varchar(255),
DNI varchar(20),
Calle varchar(255),
Num_calle int,
Piso varchar(10),
Localidad varchar(255),
Provincia varchar(255),
Telefono int,
id_vehiculo int,
constraint pk_id_cliente primary key (id_cliente)
);

create table vehiculos(
id_vehiculo int,
Marca varchar(30),
Modelo varchar(30),
Cilindrada int,
KW int,
num_chasis int,
anyo int,
kilometros int,
constraint pk_id_vehiculo primary key (id_vehiculo)
);
```

Yo en mi programa a la hora de añadir un cliente a la BD lo pueda crear con o sin vehículo asociado a el, y si mas tarde lo deseo, añadirle el vehículo si no lo he hecho o añadirle otro, osea, que pueda tener dos, aquí viene mi dilema; en la BD quiero que que el campo ´id_vehiculo´ de cliente se rellene con el campo ´id_vehiculo´ a la hora de añadirle el vehículo al cliente, pero claro, también quiero que a la hora de crear el cliente, si lo hago sin vehículo, ese campo este vacío hasta que yo decida añadirle un vehículo; y no se como hacer esas relaciones.

Comment: Un vehículo pertenecerá solo a un cliente o puede relacionarse con varios clientes a la vez?

Comment: Un vehículo puede pertenecer a ningun cliente, a uno o a muchos; basicamente quiero tener un listado de vehiculos que se irán añadiendo en el tiempo.

Comment: La [respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/22915/21) de Jose Javier es apropiada entonces. Lo que buscas se llama relación de muchos a muchos, dónde un cliente puede tener cero, uno o muchos vehículos asociados, y a la vez, un vehículo puede estar asociado a cero, uno o muchos clientes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción que tienes, es crear una tercera tabla por ejemplo Clientes-vehiculos, en la que crees esa relación. En principio con los campos `id_cliente` e `id_vehiculo`, serían suficientes.

```
create table clientes-vehiculos(
id int,
id_vehiculo int,
id_cliente int,
constraint pk_id primary key (id)
);
```

El campo `id`es por mi gusto que prefiero tener un campo clave, en lugar de tener que estar mezclando datos para una clave primaria

Comment: Creo que es importante mencionar que, en este caso, no hace falta guardar un `id_vehiculo` en la tabla cliente, y ya que la tabla de vehículos ya se llama `vehiculos`, la tabla que las relaciona no puede llamarse igual, sugeriría que se llame `cliente_vehiculos`, aunque no deja de chocarme el plural.

Comment: Las prisas hicieron que nombrase mal la tabla. Es cierto que no se pueden llamar igual.

Comment: ¿No haría falta entonces hacer ninguna clave foranea relacionando las ID's? Es que eso es lo que mas me tenía en dudas.

Comment: Las foreign key, son siempre aconsejables, para la coherencia de los datos, ahora es decisión tuya si las quieres usar. Mi recomendación es que sí

Answer (score 0):

Yo solo haria estos cambios en el Query y listo. Ademas el campo id_vehiculo en cliente aceptaria el valor `null` asi podrias dejarlo vacio hasta que decidas usarlo.

```
create table vehiculos(
id_vehiculo int not null auto_increment,
Marca varchar(30),
Modelo varchar(30),
Cilindrada int,
KW int,
num_chasis int,
anyo int,
kilometros int,
PRIMARY KEY(id_vehiculo)
);

create table cliente(
id_cliente int not null auto_increment,
Nombre varchar(255),
Apellido varchar(255),
DNI varchar(20),
Calle varchar(255),
Num_calle int,
Piso varchar(10),
Localidad varchar(255),
Provincia varchar(255),
Telefono int,
id_vehiculo int,
PRIMARY KEY(id_cliente),
FOREIGN KEY (id_vehiculo) REFERENCES vehiculos(id_vehiculo)
);
```

Comment: En este caso, cómo un cliente podría tener varios vehículos?

Comment: Ah bueno si lo que quieres es que un cliente tenga varios vehiculos asociados entonces esa estructura no te va a servir, debes tener una tabla de clientes y una tabla de vehiculos, ambos con su respectivo ID,y luego crear una tabla que se llame "clientes_vehiculos" o algo parecido, en donde enlazaras el id del vehiculo con el id del cliente, de esta manera un mismo cliente podrá tener X cantidad de vehiculos asociados.

Comment: Bueno, no yo, pero el OP lo ha dicho en los comentarios de la pregunta.